# Changing text size or line height of QGIS attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How do I change the text size in the attribute table or the height of the rows in QGIS?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full description of the problem that you are trying to solve.  Include screenshots to help explain the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no an option in QGIS to change only the text size of the attribute table. Therefore, I suggest you to add a new theme to change font size of attribute table. To do that:

- open QGIS profile folder (`Settings -> User Profiles -> Open Active Profile Folder`).
- navigate `themes` folder and create a folder and name it (i.e. `My Theme`).
- navigate the folder and create a file named `style.qss`.

[image]

- open that file in any text editor, add the following lines and save it. (You can change the values into what you desire)

```css
#AttributeTable QTableView{
    font-size: 20pt; /* font size for attribute values in the table */
}

#AttributeTable QTableView QHeaderView{        
    font-size: 40pt; /* font size for left and top header names */
}
```

- open `Settings -> Options...`. In `General` tab, choose `My Theme` as `UI Theme`. And re-open QGIS.

[image]

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, but it doesn´t work. I use notepad++ to create the style.qss file and copy/paste your code in this file. The file is in the right folder and I can choose the ui "my themes" in the options of qgis. But the size of my text doesn´t change.

Comment: I use QGIS version 3.4.8

Comment: It works, I found my fault. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @joe_gerner could you please specify what was your fault and how you fixed it?

Comment: I had to delete the comments '#AttributeTable', after that it works.

Answer (score 8):

You can adjust the text size (for the whole of QGIS) in the `Settings`->`Options` menu.

[image]

giving (at 20pt):

[image]

Comment: thanks for your advice, but is it also possible to change only the text size of the attributetable?

Comment: I don't believe so

Comment: It's possible. I will add an answer as soon as possible.